# error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `public'

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having some trouble fixing this error. I've had it work before but as soon as I added a second GetKeyDown it stopped working. Sorry if I look stupid, I'm an extreme beginner.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        public int moveSpeed = 5;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.right * moveSpeed);
        };

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.left * moveSpeed);
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: remove the `public` key word in the `void Start()` method and your code will work fine. i.e final result 

    void Start()
    {
        int moveSpeed = 5;
    }

Answer (score 3):

A) You are missing class declaration line (you still have closing bracket for it)

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Stuff : MonoBehaviour { // <-- you need class declaration (it must be the same name as file "Stuff.cs"

    public int moveSpeed = 5; // <-- B) you need to declare this variable at this scope or else Update method won't be able to see it

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.right * moveSpeed);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.left * moveSpeed);
        }
    }
} //<-- also - no semicolons after the closing brackets
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have semicolons everywhere? Anyway, thats not the problem.

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    int moveSpeed = 5; // remove public
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.D))
    {
        transform.Translate (Vector3.right * moveSpeed);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A))
    {
        transform.Translate (Vector3.left * moveSpeed);
    }

}
```

Tell me if this works.

Comment: This won't work mate. The moveSpeed variable is out of scope for the Update function.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to:

```
public int moveSpeed;

void Start () 
{
    moveSpeed = 5;
}
```

What I would really recommend is not to set the moveSpeed to 5 in the script but rather in the editor. Once you change the code to what I showed you then moveSpeed will show up in the editor inspector. Set it to whatever you want there. That way you can use the same script for objects with different speeds.